# java.util.NoSuchElementException on Arraylist while updating the message digest

Tags: java

I'm trying to browse through directories and print the contents present in them.I'm trying to add them to MessageDigest.update() method to perform md5 check sum.However,I am encountering the following error.

Below mentioned is my code

```
public class file_updated {
public static Map extra = new HashMap();
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File branches = null;
    List map_list = new ArrayList();
    Map get_val=new HashMap();
    List add_apk = new ArrayList();
    File f2 = new File("C:\\Users\\rishii\\Desktop\\new_creation");

    int count=0;
    for (File file : f2.listFiles()) {
        branches=getFilesRecursive(file);
        add_apk.add(branches);
        count=count+1;
    }

            check_sum(add_apk);




}

public  static void check_sum(List file){
 try {

     MessageDigest Digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
     Iterator it2 = file.iterator();
     int count=0;
     while(it2.hasNext())

     {
         System.out.println(count=count+1);
         System.out.println(it2.next().toString());
         Digest.update(it2.next().toString().getBytes());
     }

 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }
 }


public static   File getFilesRecursive(File file)
{

    if(file.isDirectory())
    {
        for(File file1:file.listFiles())
        {

            return file1;
        }

    }

    return  file;
}
```

}

Below attached is my stackTrace:

```
  java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854)
    at file_updated.check_sum(file_updated.java:61)
    at file_updated.main(file_updated.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is caused by

```
System.out.println(it2.next().toString());
Digest.update(it2.next().toString().getBytes());
```

You are calling the [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next()) method twice in the while loop. Calling `next()` on an iterator is how you fetch the next element so in your loop, you keep getting the next 2 elements resulting in a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` when you try to access the 2nd element at the end of the iterator.  Change to:

```
while(it2.hasNext()) {
    File f = it2.next();
    System.out.println(count=count+1);
    System.out.println(f.toString());
    Digest.update(f.toString().getBytes());
}
```